# How do I change the key for a Wi-Fi connection on an iPod Touch?

Tags: wireless-networking, ipod-touch

I use my iPod to connect to the wireless netwrok at work. There is a rotating key which changes periodically. I can't find a way of changing a key for an existing connection. Is there a way to do this, short of recreating the connection?

Comment: The SSID is not transmitted, so recreating the connection means retyping the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly, there isn't. You'll have to go into the wireless network under Settings -> WiFi and tell it to "Forget this network" and then set up the whole network all over again.